# Software respository

Tags: software-installation

Iḿ using the latest version of raspbian (new install) on a PI3. When clicking on: System Tools/Software Install, nothing happens.

Looking at the shortcut, it points to directory: /home/pi/.local/share/applications and file: pi-gpk-dbus-service.desktop

The directory .local (or the subdirectories) do no exist, and a search for the filename comes up empty.

Is the file and directory supposed to exist? and how do I otherwise access a software directory like I used to be able on the earlier version of Raspbian, and can also on Ubuntu, without resorting to command lines?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Does `.local` directory really not exits, or is it just hidden? Can you create one?

Comment: *"The directory .local (or the subdirectories) do no exist, and a search for the filename comes up empty."* -> As Dmitry points out that would be odd; more likely is the fact that whatever means you are using to look for it ignores dot files; these are considered "hidden" to reduce clutter.  However, the actual `pi-gpk-dbus-service` could be broken.

Answer (score 2):

Try making one with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Software Install
Comment=Install selected software on the system
Categories=System;
Exec=pi-gpk-dbus-service
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=system-software-install
StartupNotify=true
NoDisplay=true
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pipackage/blob/master/data/pi-gpk-dbus-service.desktop.in). If it's the only file you're missing, it should help.